# Unsupported operation RETURN_GENERATOR on select()

Tags: python, postgresql, ponyorm

I'm new at ponyorm and was trying to learn how to use ponyorm. I have the following script

```
from pony.orm import Database,PrimaryKey,select,Required

db = Database()
db.bind(
    provider='postgres', 
    user='postgres', 
    password='root', 
    host='localhost', 
    database='test')

class TestTable(db.Entity):
    _table_ = "testTable"
    columnOne = PrimaryKey(int, column="columnOne")
    columnTwo = Required(str, column="columnTwo")

db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)

result = select(row for row in TestTable)
```

I was trying to use the select() method. It throws the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Git Project Folder\test\database.py", line 18, in <module>
    result = select(r for r in TestTable)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Git Project Folder\test\env\Lib\site-packages\pony\orm\core.py", line 5560, in select
    return make_query(args, frame_depth=cut_traceback_depth+1)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Git Project Folder\test\env\Lib\site-packages\pony\orm\core.py", line 5546, in make_query
    tree, external_names, cells = decompile(gen)
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Git Project Folder\test\env\Lib\site-packages\pony\orm\decompiling.py", line 38, in decompile
    decompiler = Decompiler(codeobject)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Git Project Folder\test\env\Lib\site-packages\pony\orm\decompiling.py", line 156, in __init__
    decompiler.decompile()
  File "D:\Git Project Folder\test\env\Lib\site-packages\pony\orm\decompiling.py", line 256, in decompile
    throw(DecompileError('Unsupported operation: %s' % opname))
  File "D:\Git Project Folder\test\env\Lib\site-packages\pony\utils\utils.py", line 99, in throw
    raise exc
pony.orm.decompiling.DecompileError: Unsupported operation: RETURN_GENERATOR
```

What is wrong with my code ? i was following the example at https://docs.ponyorm.org/queries.html

Comment: Looks like that version of ponyorm isn't compatible with 3.11.  That's a new opcode.  You could try it in Python 3.10, or look for an upgrade of Pony.

Comment: @Max oh, i install pony with pip install pony few minutes ago, how do i install the newer version ?

Comment: Looking at their releases, it looks like they don't support Python 3.11.  You'll need to install Python 3.10 to use PonyORM it looks like.  Note their [releases page](https://github.com/ponyorm/pony/releases) says Python 3.6 - 3.10 at this time.

Comment: @Max noo thats mean i had to manage two python version because i dont want to uninstall the 3.11 :( . anyway thank you

Comment: @Max i just installed python 3.10.9 and the problem goes away, thank you